# How do I output a module into the main panel of a shiny app, when selecting that module from an input in the sidebar panel?

Tags: r, shiny, module, golem

I'm very new to shiny and programming in general. I'm using the Golem package and trying to set up my UI. I've created a module called 'display'. This module has been loaded into the sidebarPanel. Here is the code for the module.

```
display_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    # * Display choice ----
    # A drop down menu to navigate different parts of the app
    selectInput(ns("display_select"), label = "Display",
                choices = c("Summary", "Return from Spray", "Net Return", "Yield", "Grain Price",
                            "Disease Impact", "Mitigation by Spray", "About", "Tips"))

  ) # end tagList
}
```

```
display_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
  })
}
```

At this stage when I run the App it all displays fine. For each of these choices I would like to load the corresponding module into the main panel. For example, when I select 'About', I would like to load another module I've created called 'about', into the main panel.

Any ideas?

I've looked into reactives, conditional panels and loops, but can't seem to get it to work. Either I get nothing displaying in the main panel. Or I get the same module loading for every input. For example, the 'about' module loads for all of the inputs.

Cheers

Comment: If you are very new to shiny then write simple methods first and not modules or golem. use simple fluidpage() and write input widgets. Try css styling to get what you need in UI. Modules are slightly advanced and useful for big applications. I am doing without them even when i am putting multiple large apps within a single app. Start simple and build on that.  Some expert will certainly guide on your problem with modules but there could be simpler ways possible. thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have made some very basic shiny apps without golem. However, I've been given a project at work that's a larger, more complex app and requires me to use golem so I need to learn it.